# Xcode Swift Playgrounds - How to make default size for ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have a playground that I am building on a Mac, but intend to use on the iPad version as-well. I have a UIViewController, which I display all my content on. On the iPad playgrounds, this ViewController automatically sizes to the area of the live view. This is what I want. On the computer although, the UIViewController (programatically created) only takes up the space of an iPhone 7. I want an iPad sized area here so I can test my content on a bigger scale. How would I go about doing this (e.g.: setting default size for Xcode, but keeping the behaviour on iPad).

Thanks,

Will

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ran into this issue today. You have to set the preferredContentSize of the UIViewController.

```
viewController.preferredContentSize = viewController.view.frame.size
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful